# Remember your future in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, translation-check

what's the correct way of saying Remember your future in Latin?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What general meaning are you trying to convey with the phrase? Context can be really helpful when translating.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you mean by "your future" (big "if", English "future" is a vague word), then I would say *memento futurorum tuorum* (remember your future things).

You might want to stick an *omnium* in there, *memento omnium futurorum tuorum*. When I use the word "future" in English, I'm typically talking about all the things which will be, and not just some of them.